# Gradle Could not HEAD ...json-path-parent-0.8.1.pom target server failed to respond

Tags: java, spring, build, gradle

I'm trying to run the Spring tutorial here: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

I am fairly new to Java and Maven etc but starting to get the hang of it. Unfortunately this tutorial uses gradle for the build which I have not used at all. I've taken their code and tried to install it using the gradle wrapper from the command line and also from Intellij. I seem to be able to navigate to the repositories by browser but the gradle build is timing out

I've set the proxy server information in gradle.properties in my home directory. :

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=loprox02
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=MavenProxy
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Debug seems to indicate the proxy settings are being used e.g.

```
14:18:54.095 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyLoggingAdaper] setting 'http.proxyUser' to 'MavenProxy'
```

From both I get the output (with gradle 1.6):

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.8.1.
  Required by:
      :complete:unspecified
   > Could not parse POM http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/0.8.1/json-path-0.8.1.pom
      > Could not resolve com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-parent:0.8.1.
         > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path-parent/0.8.1/json-path-parent-0.8.1.pom'.
            > The target server failed to respond
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'tomcat'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-maven'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "http://download.java.net/maven/2"
    }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:0.9.8'
    classpath 'org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.1'
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone/'}
}

dependencies {
    def tomcatVersion = '7.0.42'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}"
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}") {
      exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', module: 'ecj'
    }

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.8.1'
    // {!begin hateoas}
    compile 'org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.7.0.RELEASE'
    // {!end hateoas}

    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.0.M2'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M2'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.0.M2'

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.5'
    runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.2'
    runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.2'
    runtime 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.9'

    provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'

    testCompile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.8.1'
    testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.3.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.6'
}

tomcatRunWar.contextPath = ''
```

Full debug output:

```
    14:22:10.834 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:22:10.840 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:22:10.846 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:22:10.850 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:22:10.854 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
14:22:10.858 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.8.1.
14:22:10.862 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   Required by:
14:22:10.866 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       :complete:unspecified
14:22:10.870 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-parent:0.8.1.
14:22:10.875 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path-parent/0.8.1/json-path-parent-0.8.1.pom'.
14:22:10.880 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]          > The target server failed to respond
14:22:10.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1.
14:22:10.890 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   Required by:
14:22:10.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       :complete:unspecified > org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.3.RELEASE
14:22:10.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:5.
14:22:10.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom'.
14:22:10.909 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]          > The target server failed to respond
14:22:10.916 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:22:10.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
14:22:10.926 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
14:22:10.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:55)
14:22:10.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
14:22:10.939 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:106)
14:22:10.943 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:74)
14:22:10.947 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:461)
14:22:10.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:202)
14:22:10.955 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
14:22:10.959 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:191)
14:22:10.963 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:103)
14:22:10.967 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75)
14:22:10.971 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:182)
14:22:10.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:98)
14:22:10.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75)
14:22:10.983 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$1.resolve(CompositeFileCollection.java:88)
14:22:10.987 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:143)
14:22:10.991 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileTree.java:30)
14:22:10.995 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getFiles(CompositeFileCollection.java:38)
14:22:10.999 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:60)
14:22:11.003 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSnapshotter.java:42)
14:22:11.007 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.InputFilesStateChangeRule.create(InputFilesStateChangeRule.java:33)
14:22:11.011 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init>(TaskUpToDateState.java:48)
14:22:11.015 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:151)
14:22:11.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:72)
14:22:11.023 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:45)
14:22:11.027 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ContextualisingTaskExecuter.execute(ContextualisingTaskExecuter.java:34)
14:22:11.032 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:39)
14:22:11.036 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
14:22:11.040 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
14:22:11.044 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
14:22:11.047 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
14:22:11.051 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
14:22:11.055 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:37)
14:22:11.059 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
14:22:11.064 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
14:22:11.068 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
14:22:11.072 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
14:22:11.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
14:22:11.080 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:282)
14:22:11.084 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:48)
14:22:11.088 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:34)
14:22:11.092 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:27)
14:22:11.096 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:89)
14:22:11.100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
14:22:11.105 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
14:22:11.109 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
14:22:11.113 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
14:22:11.116 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
14:22:11.121 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
14:22:11.125 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
14:22:11.129 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
14:22:11.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
14:22:11.137 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
```

Comment: Looks like your proxy isn't answering or something...

Comment: Try to change `json-path` to version `0.9.1`: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.jayway.jsonpath%22

Comment: Also try with the latest Gradle version (1.11).

Comment: Also double-check proxy settings and that the proxy supports basic authentication.

Comment: None of these answers help. It's not just the jayaway.jsonpath, if I comment this out I get an error on not being able to access other libraries so I guess it is some server error or proxy authentication failure (even though this doesn't seem to give an error). I've tried updating the version to 1.11. Proxy authentication is working fine when running maven, but not with gradle.